# Issues on chrome showing an embedded PDF

Tags: html, google-chrome, url, pdf

I have the following code in a html document:

```
<p>PDF sample</p>
<object data="http://www.whateverdomain.com/whatever/~/media/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

This is working in IE, Firefox but not in Chrome. Appears a grey box in the browser with no embedded pdf. When I check on "network" tab in chrome I'm receiving a HTTP 200 response but PDF is not shown.

I tried URL encode tilde "~" symbol replacing it by %7e but still its not working on Chrome.

I don't have the possibility of changing the url which is provided by an external service.
Do you have any clue on how to solve ?

Answer (score 1):

You might wish to try and use a simple iframe. At the very least I am pretty sure that works for chrome, might not work for IE though. Another alternative is using the [Google Docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer), with that you are sure to be cross browser compatible, although some pdf's might not render perfectly. The last option you have is using something like [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to render the pdf's yourself inside the browser. Gives you a lot of control and ensures that even people running computers without a pdf viewer installed (or a native pdf viewer like chrome and firefox) will be able to view the file.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the useful response. 

Iframe solution its not an option since this urls can be consumed from Mobile devices too. For other hand I see there's some bandwith restrictions using Google Docs viewer. PDF js its a good approach, so thanks for it I didnt know it.

Comment: @Josemalive: The best you can do on mobile browsers is to simply link to the pdf file in question, definitely **not** using pdf.js, as that's a pretty memory heavy library.

Comment: And btw, you must be showing a *lot* of pdf's to hit the Google Docs viewer bandwith limit...